# How to load resource from a relative path in a nodejs module?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In one of my NodeJS modules I need to access a file that is part of the module in an own folder (for unit tests). It tried `__dirname` in the calling file with a relative path to that resource file. This works when running from within vscode, but not whe executing `npm test` in a terminal. In that case the constructed path is one level off. How can that be?

I have to add that I'm using typescript for coding and Mocha for unit tests.

Simply logging `__filename` helps a bit here. It shows that under vscode the executing file is the transpiled JS file, while under Mocha it's the typescript source file. I run:

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register
```

for my tests. Any idea how to overcome this and ensure the correct path is used (other than testing if `__filename` ends with `.ts`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out to be simple. Instead of running mocha with ts code let it use the transpiled code. Only requires a transpilation run before testing:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "tsc",
    "install": "tsc",
    "test": "tsc && mocha out/test"
  },
```